# How to link MinGW in cmd or bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, linker, mingw, lib

MinGW v.8.1.0
I'm learning how to work with a compiler but for some stuff, I can't find the answer.
In a simple situation where all I need is my code I can write in CMD:

```
gcc [list c files] -o main.exe
```

And same in a bat file:

```
del main.exe
gcc [list c files] -o main.exe
main.exe
pause
```

Now I want to make something using `#include <windows.h>` and that means linking to user32.lib.
Looking at closest thing in `gcc --h` there is `-Xlinker <arg>    Pass <arg> on to the linker`.
My assumption is that my command should be:

```
gcc [list c files] -o main.exe -Xlinker [list of *.lib files]
```

Which doesn't work. I want to understand how to link to window's built-in libs and how to do that to other available libs and how to make it easy with bat files.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be difficult be specific if you don't provide the exact line of code you have. If `MinGW` is installed properly, it will know how to find the static libraries. It should include most of the `Windows` static libraries (`user32`, `comctl32`, `comdlg32`, `ole32`, etc).

```
gcc [list c files] -o main.exe -luser32 -lcomctl32 -comdlg32 [any other library here]
```

By the way, the naming convention is the following: if the static library filename is `libuser32.a`, the link flag should be `-luser32.a`